# Fusion Charts Zoomline React Error: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 6 failed

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I followed this link to implement a zoomline chart - https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/line-area-charts/line-chart-with-zooming-and-panning?framework=react

I have the exact same code as they have

I have already looked into this link and tried to import but the zoomline chart seems to keep throwing the error

[fusioncharts react error loading chunks failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605214/fusioncharts-react-error-loading-chunks-failed/61033642#61033642)

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-engelbart-m26zq

Answer (score 2):

```
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import zoomline from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.zoomline";
import ReactFusioncharts from "react-fusioncharts";

ReactFusioncharts.fcRoot(FusionCharts,charts,zoomline);
```

Comment: I was trying with `ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, PowerCharts, FusionTheme)` but did not work. I have the same format for sparkline and quagechart but for powerchart it did not work, But te above answer worked for powercharts

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code for zoomline -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";

import Zoom from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.zoomline";
import FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
import ReactFC from "react-fusioncharts";

ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Zoom, FusionTheme);

const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Unique Website Visitors",
    subcaption: "Last year",
    yaxisname: "Unique Visitors",
    xaxisname: "Date",
    yaxisminValue: "800",
    yaxismaxValue: "1400",
    pixelsPerPoint: "0",
    pixelsPerLabel: "30",
    lineThickness: "1",
    compactdatamode: "1",
    dataseparator: "|",
    labelHeight: "30",
    theme: "fusion"
  },
  categories: [
    {
      category:
        "Jan 01|Jan 02|Jan 03|Jan 04|Jan 05|Jan 06|Jan 07|Jan 08|Jan 09|Jan 10|Jan 11|Jan 12|Jan 13|Jan 14|Jan 15|Jan 16|Jan 17|Jan 18|Jan 19|Jan 20|Jan 21|Jan 22|Jan 23|Jan 24|Jan 25|Jan 26|Jan 27|Jan 28|Jan 29|Jan 30|Jan 31|Feb 01|Feb 02|Feb 03|Feb 04|Feb 05|Feb 06|Feb 07|Feb 08|Feb 09|Feb 10|Feb 11|Feb 12|Feb 13|Feb 14|Feb 15|Feb 16|Feb 17|Feb 18|Feb 19|Feb 20|Feb 21|Feb 22|Feb 23|Feb 24|Feb 25|Feb 26|Feb 27|Feb 28|Mar 01|Mar 02|Mar 03|Mar 04|Mar 05|Mar 06|Mar 07|Mar 08|Mar 09|Mar 10|Mar 11|Mar 12|Mar 13|Mar 14|Mar 15|Mar 16|Mar 17|Mar 18|Mar 19|Mar 20|Mar 21|Mar 22|Mar 23|Mar 24|Mar 25|Mar 26|Mar 27|Mar 28|Mar 29|Mar 30|Mar 31|Apr 01|Apr 02|Apr 03|Apr 04|Apr 05|Apr 06|Apr 07|Apr 08|Apr 09|Apr 10|Apr 11|Apr 12|Apr 13|Apr 14|Apr 15|Apr 16|Apr 17|Apr 18|Apr 19|Apr 20|Apr 21|Apr 22|Apr 23|Apr 24|Apr 25|Apr 26|Apr 27|Apr 28|Apr 29|Apr 30|May 01|May 02|May 03|May 04|May 05|May 06|May 07|May 08|May 09|May 10|May 11|May 12|May 13|May 14|May 15|May 16|May 17|May 18|May 19|May 20|May 21|May 22|May 23|May 24|May 25|May 26|May 27|May 28|May 29|May 30|May 31|Jun 01|Jun 02|Jun 03|Jun 04|Jun 05|Jun 06|Jun 07|Jun 08|Jun 09|Jun 10|Jun 11|Jun 12|Jun 13|Jun 14|Jun 15|Jun 16|Jun 17|Jun 18|Jun 19|Jun 20|Jun 21|Jun 22|Jun 23|Jun 24|Jun 25|Jun 26|Jun 27|Jun 28|Jun 29|Jun 30|Jul 01|Jul 02|Jul 03|Jul 04|Jul 05|Jul 06|Jul 07|Jul 08|Jul 09|Jul 10|Jul 11|Jul 12|Jul 13|Jul 14|Jul 15|Jul 16|Jul 17|Jul 18|Jul 19|Jul 20|Jul 21|Jul 22|Jul 23|Jul 24|Jul 25|Jul 26|Jul 27|Jul 28|Jul 29|Jul 30|Jul 31|Aug 01|Aug 02|Aug 03|Aug 04|Aug 05|Aug 06|Aug 07|Aug 08|Aug 09|Aug 10|Aug 11|Aug 12|Aug 13|Aug 14|Aug 15|Aug 16|Aug 17|Aug 18|Aug 19|Aug 20|Aug 21|Aug 22|Aug 23|Aug 24|Aug 25|Aug 26|Aug 27|Aug 28|Aug 29|Aug 30|Aug 31|Sep 01|Sep 02|Sep 03|Sep 04|Sep 05|Sep 06|Sep 07|Sep 08|Sep 09|Sep 10|Sep 11|Sep 12|Sep 13|Sep 14|Sep 15|Sep 16|Sep 17|Sep 18|Sep 19|Sep 20|Sep 21|Sep 22|Sep 23|Sep 24|Sep 25|Sep 26|Sep 27|Sep 28|Sep 29|Sep 30|Oct 01|Oct 02|Oct 03|Oct 04|Oct 05|Oct 06|Oct 07|Oct 08|Oct 09|Oct 10|Oct 11|Oct 12|Oct 13|Oct 14|Oct 15|Oct 16|Oct 17|Oct 18|Oct 19|Oct 20|Oct 21|Oct 22|Oct 23|Oct 24|Oct 25|Oct 26|Oct 27|Oct 28|Oct 29|Oct 30|Oct 31|Nov 01|Nov 02|Nov 03|Nov 04|Nov 05|Nov 06|Nov 07|Nov 08|Nov 09|Nov 10|Nov 11|Nov 12|Nov 13|Nov 14|Nov 15|Nov 16|Nov 17|Nov 18|Nov 19|Nov 20|Nov 21|Nov 22|Nov 23|Nov 24|Nov 25|Nov 26|Nov 27|Nov 28|Nov 29|Nov 30|Dec 01|Dec 02|Dec 03|Dec 04|Dec 05|Dec 06|Dec 07|Dec 08|Dec 09|Dec 10|Dec 11|Dec 12|Dec 13|Dec 14|Dec 15|Dec 16|Dec 17|Dec 18|Dec 19|Dec 20|Dec 21|Dec 22|Dec 23|Dec 24|Dec 25|Dec 26|Dec 27|Dec 28|Dec 29|Dec 30|Dec 31"
    }
  ],
  dataset: [
    {
      seriesname: "harrysfoodmart.com",
      data:
        "978|976|955|981|992|964|973|949|985|962|977|955|988|959|985|965|991|985|966|989|960|944|976|980|940|941|945|952|973|946|951|983|942|964|937|942|963|971|969|967|934|935|956|974|930|936|935|973|979|990|994|992|994|984|991|986|963|985|1006|965|958|976|993|974|995|989|966|965|1011|995|1007|978|985|1012|997|985|1004|987|986|981|991|982|992|983|1018|994|976|989|1022|989|1002|983|1015|1006|1005|1003|1017|1014|995|1007|1001|1019|1012|1005|1027|1011|1013|1035|1010|1011|1011|1036|1041|1005|1005|997|1012|1032|1025|1020|998|1018|1000|1009|1005|1004|1042|1047|1021|1032|1019|1038|1050|1037|1019|1018|1035|1055|1028|1049|1013|1028|1023|1054|1041|1051|1069|1051|1072|1049|1054|1035|1072|1042|1048|1083|1054|1048|1065|1046|1055|1056|1085|1046|1048|1048|1068|1089|1074|1078|1046|1052|1082|1052|1067|1058|1051|1052|1082|1060|1076|1077|1059|1070|1082|1093|1100|1089|1079|1075|1087|1089|1088|1106|1107|1067|1076|1101|1094|1078|1097|1094|1083|1066|1079|1111|1100|1085|1091|1095|1081|1091|1077|1095|1107|1083|1116|1118|1101|1111|1096|1077|1086|1117|1087|1105|1107|1094|1112|1101|1084|1094|1125|1099|1108|1084|1099|1120|1122|1092|1120|1121|1094|1114|1099|1129|1095|1125|1127|1121|1129|1110|1097|1136|1110|1098|1131|1125|1144|1104|1117|1105|1105|1145|1102|1143|1115|1147|1149|1129|1108|1109|1130|1153|1121|1127|1133|1120|1155|1120|1147|1118|1117|1145|1152|1145|1130|1157|1135|1115|1156|1163|1131|1123|1137|1151|1160|1152|1166|1144|1137|1124|1151|1129|1133|1143|1139|1171|1135|1132|1174|1170|1163|1175|1152|1142|1160|1148|1173|1158|1160|1151|1142|1168|1153|1143|1157|1142|1172|1186|1176|1185|1175|1178|1184|1166|1148|1166|1186|1187|1180|1179|1161|1174|1155|1172|1173|1179|1149|1170|1175|1162|1151|1152|1163|1155|1197|1174|1199|1180|1160|1174|1159|1168|1160"
    },
    {
      seriesname: "harrysfashion.com",
      data:
        "1053|1057|1084|1082|1098|1055|1068|1067|1074|1056|1067|1078|1079|1084|1041|1052|1066|1080|1049|1051|1049|1044|1083|1053|1038|1077|1046|1067|1053|1033|1047|1055|1031|1074|1031|1041|1071|1057|1035|1070|1050|1069|1054|1049|1022|1044|1049|1058|1064|1088|1093|1103|1085|1072|1104|1106|1078|1061|1078|1105|1105|1062|1076|1074|1114|1069|1091|1086|1094|1072|1079|1088|1082|1075|1110|1120|1108|1102|1090|1088|1092|1102|1110|1111|1085|1113|1110|1116|1095|1105|1105|1122|1133|1132|1093|1097|1120|1105|1135|1106|1108|1135|1098|1136|1122|1113|1113|1145|1103|1127|1104|1126|1147|1120|1119|1120|1132|1107|1149|1147|1149|1141|1145|1152|1117|1144|1157|1134|1157|1120|1125|1153|1141|1132|1158|1134|1166|1167|1170|1163|1139|1171|1145|1156|1158|1154|1196|1196|1169|1174|1174|1195|1161|1201|1208|1188|1182|1188|1162|1174|1174|1211|1189|1211|1172|1211|1179|1199|1216|1184|1209|1181|1186|1174|1185|1220|1206|1190|1206|1201|1190|1209|1208|1189|1195|1188|1193|1206|1214|1205|1215|1200|1194|1210|1205|1236|1226|1208|1228|1235|1197|1197|1198|1224|1220|1210|1226|1244|1228|1241|1237|1201|1208|1238|1213|1222|1213|1249|1222|1221|1230|1223|1214|1251|1234|1220|1240|1213|1252|1224|1222|1234|1262|1255|1225|1226|1242|1240|1250|1265|1235|1228|1261|1221|1230|1235|1260|1273|1253|1268|1258|1233|1258|1248|1230|1270|1246|1242|1246|1253|1253|1257|1253|1266|1248|1247|1257|1245|1281|1271|1272|1248|1292|1251|1253|1257|1259|1288|1252|1297|1290|1268|1291|1258|1263|1254|1302|1279|1272|1271|1281|1261|1263|1289|1294|1272|1296|1264|1282|1268|1296|1280|1281|1277|1277|1292|1266|1310|1288|1312|1308|1300|1289|1273|1282|1300|1322|1301|1314|1296|1305|1305|1327|1323|1295|1314|1298|1312|1330|1293|1309|1286|1309|1332|1300|1295|1325|1322|1305|1323|1300|1308|1299|1324|1338|1313|1329|1331|1299|1329|1344|1335|1342|1307|1314|1326|1331|1328|1328|1311|1352|1328|1309|1311|1312"
    }
  ]
};

const chartConfigs = {
  type: "zoomline",
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
  dataFormat: "json",
  dataSource: dataSource
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactFC {...chartConfigs} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is the demo fiddle for zoom - https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-fire-ym4v0jk551?file=/src/index.js:0-7402

Hope it would help you.